# Enum can not be used for Fixed constant?

Tags: java, enums

I am using following to define fixed set of constants

```
private enum MENU_OPTIONS {
   MENU_SEND_SMS,
   MENU_COPY_SMS,
   MENU_ADD_SMS,
   MENU_POST_FACEBOOK,
   MENU_TWEET
}
```

and I have a method which accepts INT

```
menu.add (int, int, int, String);
```

so when I provide "MENU_OPTIONS.MENU_SEND_SMS" to the above method, it is reporting error

```
menu.add(0, MENU_SEND_SMS, 0, ); // error: The method add(int, int, int, CharSequence) in the type Menu is not applicable for the arguments (int, FavoriteSMSFragment.MENU_OPTIONS, int, String)
```

So If I want to use a fixed set of constants, how should I define the ENUM?

Answer (score 3):

An enum is a class. The type of `MENU_OPTIONS.MENU_SEND_SMS` is `MENU_OPTIONS` (which, since it's a class which represents a single menu option, should be named `MenuOption`).

Your `add()` method should thus take an argument of type `MenuOption` and not an argument of type `int`. This is much safer, because it documents what the method expects (int is much more vague than MenuOption), and because you won't be able to pass any value other than the values defined in the enum (whereas any invalid int value could be passed to a method taking an int as argument).

Answer (score 2):

Enums in java are not like enums in C or C++. They essentially boil down to static instances of a class. [This article explains it well and with examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).  I believe you need `MENU_SEND_SMS.ordinal()` for the way you're doing it now, but you could probably do better by using the enums as a class like they are (as in the examples from the docs I linked)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, an enumeration is more like a named instance of a class.An [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. `MENU_SEND_SMS` is of type `MENU_OPTIONS`. It is not of primitive `int` type.It doesn't work the way `enums` are used in other language like C.

**Three thing you can do:**

1) Change the type of argument

```
menu.add (int, MENU_OPTIONS, int, String);
```

2) If you still sustain the existing method definition:

```
menu.add (int, int, int, String);
```

Then invoke as:

```
MENU_OPTIONS option = MENU_OPTIONS.MENU_SEND_SMS
menu.add(0, option.ordinal(), 0, "someString");
```

3) Define the enum as:

```
public enum MENU_OPTIONS {
      MENU_SEND_SMS(0),
      MENU_COPY_SMS(1),
      MENU_ADD_SMS(2),
      MENU_POST_FACEBOOK(3),
      MENU_TWEET(4);

     private final int option;
     private MENU_OPTIONS (int option) {
        this.option= option;
     }

     public int getOption() {
        return option;
    }
 }
```

And use it as:

```
menu.add(0, MENU_OPTIONS.MENU_SEND_SMS.getOption(), 0, "someString");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(MENU_OPTIONS.MENU_ADD_SMS);
```

It'll print **MENU_ADD_SMS** (of type `MENU_OPTIONS`)

You probably want to get the int value from the `ENUM` by using **[ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29)**:

`System.out.println(MENU_OPTIONS.MENU_ADD_SMS.ordinal());`

Now it'll print **2**, as the method except.

Or, alliteratively, you can change the method so it accepts an `MENU_OPTION` instead of `int`.